# Does a sotah make a bracha?

Tags: halacha, blessing, water, sotah-secluded-woman

Before drinking the sotah water does the woman make a blessing? If so would it be shahakol or something else?

Comment: You only say shehakol on water if drinking because of thirst, so no shehakol here. I don't know about a Birkat HaMitzvah.

Comment: @DoubleAA Don't you say it also if you're drinking for some other reason but are thirsty and the drink will quench your thirst?

Comment: I would assume the dirt makes it pagum and unfit for human drinking thereby negating any theoretical bracha

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6834&st=&pgnum=98&hilite= found this on a google chat

Answer (score 9):

Sefer Otzar Palos HaTorah pg.161 brings down that no *birkas hanehenin* is said on Sotah water since it has a bad flavor.

Rav Chaim Kaniefsky rules that one does not make a *birkas hamitzvah* on Sotah water. He brings a proof from *Berachos* 51b which says "one does not make a bracha on calamities".

It is also noted that the Sotah who knows that she is innocent still won't say a *beracha* on the Sotah water since her predicament only came through suspicion of aveirah.  This is like the Rashba (Shu"t §18) who holds that one does not make a *birkas hamitzvah* on something which came through a sin. (‘Taama D'krah’ by Rav Chaim Kanievsky - Parshas Naso).

Comment: [Abudirham](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Abudirham) explicitly addresses the question [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Abudarham%2C_Third_Gate%3B_Blessings_on_Commandments.17?vhe=Abudarham._Lisbon,_1489.&with=all&lang=bi).

Comment: @Oliver the Abudarham perhaps speaks on "על אכילת סוטה"

Comment: Does that mean you don't make a birkas hamitzvah on bringing or eating any chatas or asham?

Answer (score 6):

You only recite a bracha on water if you are thirsty.<sup>1</sup> Since the sotah is not drinking the water to quench her thirst, there would be no bracha. As for birkat hamitzvah I don't know.

The question has been raised in the comments about what if the sotah was thirsty when she drank the water. It seems (at least in the way I interpret it) that according to the Mishnah Berurah, she would recite a bracha.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1 Shulchan Aruch, O.C. 204:7. Borei Nefashot would not be said as well. See also Brachot 44a and Rambam Brachot 8:1.</sup>

<sup>2 Mishnah Berurah 204:2. The case is drinking water in order to swallow a pill. If the person drinks the water in order to swallow the pill *and* to quench his thirst, according to this opinion he would recite a bracha on the water. Perhaps if the sotah was thirsty, she would recite a bracha as well.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Following up on @[Ezra](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11486/ezra)'s question as to to whether a Birchas Hamitzvah is made,     and adding  support to @[sam's](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1418/sam) answer which states that no Bircas Hamitzvah would be made:</sup>

The **[Rivash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Sheshet)** (1326–1408) explicitly writes that a Bircas Hamitzvah **wouldn't** be recited on a Sotah drinking the water ([Teshuvos HaRivash, *siman* 398](https://www.sefaria.org/Teshuvot_HaRivash.398.8?lang=bi)):

> שאין מברכין על הקלקלה כמו שאין הכהן המשקה את הסוטה מברך
>
> we don't make a blessing on something negative (lit. "cursing), much like the Kohein who administers the drinking of the Sotah water doesn't recite a blessing.

Comment: A bit late to the game :) Rivash was quoted over four years ago in the link at [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48936/does-a-sotah-make-a-bracha#comment130069_48936) comment to OP’s question (top of left column).

Comment: @Oliver however, the best place for links like that is expounded in answers.  Comments are easy to miss.